# Get a file's emblem from command line?

Tags: nautilus, command-line, bash, emblem

I'd like to be able to determine what emblem a file has from the command line.  Is there a way to determine this?  Also, is there a way to apply emblems from the command line?

I usually have a cron job that trashes files over 7 days old in my ~/Downloads, but I'd like to be able to only delete files that don't have a particular emblem (my seeding torrents).  I've been applying these emblems manually, but if I can automate that as well, that'd be awesome.

My usual cron job is just a simple find command:

```
find /home/zach/Downloads/ -ctime +7 -exec trash {} \;
```

Edit:

I solved my own question.

Bonus:

To elaborate on exactly what I'm doing, I use `deluge-torrent` to manage my downloads.  I am now using the execute plugin to run this script on torrent complete:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# deluge gives the download directory name as the third argument
gvfs-set-attribute -t stringv "$3" metadata::emblems ubuntuone-unsynchronized
```

I then created my `trasher.sh` (this requires the `trash-cli` package):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
[[ "$(gvfs-info -a metadata::emblems $*)" =~ "ubuntuone-unsynchronized" ]] || trash "$*"
```

Now, I just modify my cron to:

```
find /home/zach/Downloads/ -maxdepth 1 -ctime +7 -exec /home/zach/Scripts/trasher.sh {} \;
```

And voila!  Now Deluge can manage its downloads, while my cleanup script can safely cleanup old files without interfering with seeding torrents.

Comment: What a good idea! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`<Juhaz>` in ##gnome on freenode got it.

`gvfs-info -a metadata::emblems FOLDER`

will retrieve the emblem of a folder/file and

`gvfs-set-attribute -t stringv FOLDER metadata::emblems EMBLEM`

will allow you to set emblem of the folder/file.

Comment: And metadata is stored on ~/home/.local/share/gvfs-metadata. There is one file per partition/volumen if I understand it right. Binary files. Ugly is you ask me, but likely faster than xml files.

Comment: Thats where they first pointed me to when I asked in ##gnome.  Lots of binary .log files.  I made the mistake of `cat *`'ing the dir.  It also seems that the files there never get cleaned out?

Comment: Doesn't work on 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

[This post explains](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?s=6242e16211815e7cf47305d11f23152b&p=5777855&postcount=2) how emblem information is stored in a XML file under ~/.nautilus/metafiles. First you'd need to test if the XML related to each download exists, and if so, whether it contains the emblem of your choice.

Comment: My `~/.nautilus/` folder is 100% empty...

Comment: Old info, this was changed on Lucid. And BTW I will also love to know where does nautilus store them now.

Comment: Yeah, I already read that post (sorry, should have specified).  But as others have commented, that information is no longer relevant.  I even tried searching for .xml files in my ~ and nothing came up other than some things for other programs.