# How to make nautilus recognize emblems changed from the command line

Tags: nautilus, command-line, bash, emblem

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any tweak to bring back emblems in Nautilus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83226/is-there-any-tweak-to-bring-back-emblems-in-nautilus)

I am trying to write myself a nautilus script. I need to change emblems of files in this script. I discovered how to do the same from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3403/get-a-files-emblem-from-command-line).

I however see that the changed emblems are not reflected in the nautilus browser until I reboot(I am going to presume that this means that a restart of nautilus is required). Is there I way I can do this any other way?

By other way I mean without restarting nautilus, like how the emblems are changed instantly when done through "right click -> Properties -> Emblems"?

Comment: @nitstorm, On second thoughts, I wish to not have the question closed. It is a valid question and useful too. I will flag your comment to the moderator.

Comment: There is an interesting script here with a method to do autorefresh - does this work for you? http://askubuntu.com/a/87580/14356

Answer (score 1):

You can use `nautilus -q` to only restart nautilus.

Comment: I meant to ask "without restarting nautilus"