# See in nautilus which videos have already been watched

Tags: nautilus, video, nautilus-elementary

Is there any possibility to see in nautilus or nautilus elementary which videos in my video folder have already been watched?

Answer (score 4):

As a slight variation of the suggestion of @type - you can set "emblems" on files, which are small overlay icons, available through the Properties dialog.

And, if you feel really adventurous (but not adventurous enough to write your own plugin), you can "automate" the process:

- investigate where Gnome stores file emblems. See this [link](http://www.kryogenix.org/days/2006/10/23/find-files-with-an-emblem) for some initial details (update - the info there is obsolete, see below).
- write a simple script which adds an emblem to the file and then launches the media player. The above link even has a sample script for *reading* the emblems
- set up the script as the preferred application for opening video files

Of course, the script won't be able to tell whether you finished watching the video, whether you were watching carefully or if you want to re-watch it again - you can set emblems manually for that.

UPD: Actually, here's how to [set emblems on a file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3403/get-a-files-emblem-from-command-line). The rest is trivial...

UPD2: Here's a simple script which labels a file and opens it in totem:

```
#!/bin/sh
gvfs-set-attribute -t stringv "$1" metadata::emblems favorite
totem $1 &
```

Save it somewhere and set executable bit. Then you just right-click on a video - Open with - Other application - Use a custom command - [x] Remember this application - enjoy! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
startme=date %s
vlc $1
endme=date %s
timewatched=$(( $start-$end ))
```

I have a script which goes WAY beyond this, including remembering videos in a "favorites" folder that is rescored after every viewing. This is based on a combination of time watched, total time watched for all videos, and number of times viewed for that file and for all files. I also have one of these for image galleries and might make one for music, but what's really needed is for this stuff to be incorporated into geeqie, vlc and whatevermusicplayerthatdoesntsuckorusemonothatwillbesupportedinthefuture.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the file and add a note via the Properties. With any text therein, the file icon gets an overlay image resembling a note (which in your case cud mean that this video is watched).

Comment: what are the benefits of adding a Note compared to Emblems? The latter seem to be more suited for the task - it's even possible to use different emblems for good/bad videos...

Comment: nice! never tried these (nor the notes ;) -- thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is not an inherent ability in either nautilus or nautilus-elementary and there aren't any extensions that have this functionality.

So no, unless you can [develop an extension](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14700/how-can-i-write-nautilus-scripts-in-python/14705#14705) to do this. I imagine such an extension would need to use [zeitgeist](http://zeitgeist-project.com/) to accurately tell if a video has been watched.