# How to preserve icons and emblems when copying files

Tags: command-line, icons, emblem

When I copy a file through Nautilus its emblem or icon is preserved, but if I do it with `cp` or `rsync` through CLI it isn't. Why, and how to fix it?

By preserved I mean that icons that I have manually changed stay like that when copying through Nautilus, and are otherwise reset to the default icons when copying through CLI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a small Perl script that solves this issue, [metasave](https://github.com/despens/metasave). It saves nautilus metadata in the form of a shell script that you need to run on the destination system.

If you want to copy files on the command line and preserve their metadata, you need to use `gvfs-copy`, Gnome's replacement of `cp`.

Comment: I didn't know about `gvfs-copy`, thank you. It's unfortunate that there isn't a `gvfs-rsync`.

Answer (score 1):

**WHY:** Emblems are not a part of the file itself, they're stored somewhere inside Gnome - when you copy files using Nautilus, it is able to update the metadata in Gnome because Nautilus is a Gnome app and is aware of the existance of labels and emblems.

`cp`, `rsync` and other non-Gnome commands, on the other hand, know nothing about labels and emblems and can do nothing to preserve them.

**HOW TO FIX:** There may be no good way to fix it for every command-line utility which copies files. For some selected commands, such as `cp` you may look at writing some wrappers which set the emblems of the target files to match the emblems of the source files. [This post](https://askubuntu.com/a/60391/14564) may give you some pointers at how to set emblems from command line

Comment: Are all emblems icons? Does what you described for emblem apply for icons in general as well?

Comment: Great link ! Didn't know how to do that. In any case my problem here is that when I rsync a folder icons in dest are reset.

Comment: What do you mean by "icons are reset"? Do you mean the main file icon is getting changed? From what is it getting changed to what?

Answer (score 0):

Try using rsync with the archive flag:

```
rsync -av <source> <dest>
```

It could be that nautilus is preserving permissions such as executable and rsync & cp unless told are not.

Comment: Doesn't fix it.